# Confusion about the sentence "if the companies or individuals......as is well known in the west...."

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I was reading [this](https://islamqa.info/en/88206) answer on an Islamic Q&A website and the following sentence confused me:

> With regard to other types of meat, **if the companies or individuals
>   who produce meat are people of the Book, Jews or Christians, and it is
>   not known from them that they kill the animal by electric shock,
>   strangling or striking it on the head, as is well known in the west**,
>   then this meat is halaal.

Does the author wish to say that it is well known that western countries DO NOT kill the animal by electric shock, strangling or striking on the head OR does he mean it is well known that western countries DO use these methods of killing animals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's a confusing way to express the simple statement.  The author is saying that if the slaughterhouses are run by "People of the Book", but they have not documented that they use one of the forbidden methods to kill the animal, then you can assume the animal has been killed using an allowed method and the meat is halaal.

The phrase "as is well known in the West" implies the author thinks Western nations commonly practice forbidden methods of slaughtering animals, which is why someone trying to keep halaal needs to be careful.

Comment: _The phrase "as is well known in the West" implies the author thinks Western nations are familiar with these humane slaughter methods, but may not use these methods._ Do you mean by this line that killing by electric shock, strangling, etc. are humane methods of slaughter?

Comment: Additionally, are you also suggesting, through the same line, that the author thinks the west DOES use strangling, electric shock, etc. to kill animals?

Comment: I understand the essence of the author's claim. I was simply confused about the particular statement I highlighted in my question above.

Comment: @a_sid sorry, I misread the statement.   I confused *halal* with *haram*.   Let me revise the answer

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchy of modifiers here is approximately like this:

```
if ( ( the companies or individuals 
       ( who produce meat ) 
       are people of the Book, Jews or Christians,
     )
     and
     ( it is not known from them
       ( that they kill the animal
         by electric shock, strangling or striking it on the head,
         ( as is well known in the West )
       )
     )
   ),
then ( this meat is halaal ).
```

It implies that the listed methods of killing are widely used in the West, resulting in meat that is not Halaal. The contrast between **not known** versus **well known** also supports this interpretation.